# How to tackle this function counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> Let $n ≥ 1$ be an integer. A function $f : \{1, 2, \ldots , n\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$ is called *great*, if there is at least one integer $i$ in $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ for which $f(i) = i$. Determine the number of great functions.

Doing some textbook problems but now I'm stuck on this one. I was wondering how to approach this problem? The book has no answer key or explanations so a bit hard to self-teach. Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not count the not-great functions instead?

Comment: Functions that leave no element in its original position are called [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangements).  You need to subtract them from the number of functions $f: \{1, 2, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  Also, please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.